# iOS Swift How do you Secure Encode/Decode a TimeInterval for compatibility with NSSecureCoding?

Tags: ios, swift, core-data, nssecurecoding

I have a variable

```
var pausedTime: TimeInterval?
```

I want to encode & decode it with `NSSecureCoding`

So far I have this for encoding:

```
aCoder.encode(pausedTime, forKey: "Pause")
```

and this for decoding, treating the `TimeInterval` as a `Double`:

```
if aDecoder.containsValue(forKey: "Pause") {
    pausedTime = aDecoder.decodeDouble(forKey: "Pause")
}
```

But this is not working and resulting in the error:

> [error] fault: exception raised during multi-threaded fetch ***
>   -[NSKeyedUnarchiver decodeDoubleForKey:]: value for key (pausedTime) is not a 64-bit float ({
>       "__NSCoderInternalErrorCode" = 4864; })

Please could someone provide me with the *correct* way to secure encode/decode a `TimeInterval`?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

First, `TimeInterval` is exactly a `Double` (it's just a typealias). This is useful to know in case you expect any specialness about `TimeInterval`. There isn't any.

In your case, `pausedTime` is not a `TimeInterval`, however. It's a `TimeInterval?`. You're probably winding up calling the `encode(Any?, forKey:)` overload, and that's probably boxing your double into an `NSNumber`.

To fix that, you should make sure you're encoding a `Double`. For example:

```
if let pausedTime = pausedTime {
   aCoder.encode(pausedTime, forKey: "Pause")
}
```

or

```
aCoder.encode(pausedTime ?? 0.0, forKey: "Pause")
```